# gstreamer: signal name 'add-turn-server' is invalid

Tags: gstreamer

According to [gstreamer's docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c#webrtcbin::add-turn-server), `add-turn-server` is an action signal of `webrtcbin`. But when I try to call it, I get an error:

```
  pipe1 = gst_parse_launch (pipeline_command, &error);
  webrtc1 = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipe1), "sendrecv");
  gboolean add_turn_server_result = FALSE;
  g_signal_emit_by_name (webrtc1, "add-turn-server", turn_str, &add_turn_server_result);
```

error at runtime:

```
(@:19123): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 13:02:21.408: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:3493:
signal name 'add-turn-server' is invalid for instance '0x7f1003e180' $f type 'GstWebRTCBin'
```

I'm using gstreamer 1.14.5:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 --version
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.14.5
GStreamer 1.14.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a possible reason: `gst-inspect-1.0 webrtcbin` doesn't show `add-turn-server` as an action signal. However, if I installed gstreamer 1.18, the same command does show it:

```
                                                                gint arg0);
  "add-turn-server" :  gboolean user_function (GstElement* object,
                                               gchararray arg0);
  "create-data-channel" :  GstWebRTCDataChannel* user_function (GstElement* object,
                                                                 gchararray arg0,
                                                                 GstStructure* arg1);
```

Hence, it's a version issue.